# Adding together values from a object in an array

Tags: java, arrays, object, return-value, addition

I'm trying to add all the cost values and quantity values and multiply them  together from my array object `list[i]` in my method `getTotalCost` (as seen in the code):

```
public class GroceryList {
    private int i;

    GroceryItemOrder list[] = new GroceryItemOrder[10];

    public void addItem(String name, double cost, int quantity) {
        try {
            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                list[i] = new GroceryItemOrder(name, cost, quantity);

                if (list[i] == list[9] && list[i] != null) {
                    System.out.format("%6s %-15S %10gKR. %4d stk.%n", "",
                            list[i].getName_Food(),
                            list[i].getCost_Food(),
                            list[i].getQuantity_Food()
                    );
                }
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("You put too many groceries in your cart!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void getTotalCost(){
        System.out.println();

        try {
            double totalAmount;
            totalAmount = list[i].getCost_Food() * list[i].getQuantity_Food();
            System.out.println("The Total Amount is: " + totalAmount);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}

this below is my main class:    

package com.company;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GroceryList gL = new GroceryList();

    receipt();

    gL.addItem("Bananer",10,6);
    gL.addItem("Toiletpapir",40,2);
    gL.addItem("Svinekød",30,1);
    gL.addItem("Papir",25,1);
    gL.addItem("Sødmælk",10,3);
    gL.addItem("Færdigret",15,5);

    //=130
    /*
    gL.addItem("Kylling",10,2);
    gL.addItem("Kaffe",10,2);
    gL.addItem("Bønner",10,2);
    gL.addItem("Kage",10,2);
    //*/

    gL.getTotalCost();


}

public static void receipt(){
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.printf("%9S %1S%n","","\"~discount supermarket receipt~\"");
    System.out.printf("%15S %15S %15S%n","Grocery:","Cost:","Quantity:");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

}

This is the output error I'm getting now when removing the try/catch:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
>       at com.company.GroceryList.getTotalCost(GroceryList.java:33)
>       at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:26)

I want to get:

> The Total Amount is: xxx

Comment: Instead of catching the exception, try letting it bubble up and print the stack trace - that way you can see exactly what went wrong (i.e. remove the `try ... catch` temporarily)

Comment: Can you post how this Class is used .I mean in your main method?

Comment: Look closely at your `i` variable. Use your debugger to watch that variable...you may be surprised what's happening.

Comment: I put the main class up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must keep track of the number of items added to your array. 
So declare this variable at the class level, instead of `i`:

```
private int counter = 0;
```

Your `addItem()` method contains a `for` loop. Why?
This method should add 1 item to `list`, so change to this:

```
public void addItem(String name, double cost, int quantity) {
    if (counter == list.length) {
        System.out.println("Your cart is full! No more items can be added.");
        return;
    }
    list[counter] = new GroceryItemOrder(name, cost, quantity);
    counter++;
}
```

Now in `getTotalCost()` you do need a `for` loop to iterate through all the items in the list and get the total you need:

```
public void getTotalCost(){
    double totalAmount = 0.0;
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        totalAmount += list[i].getCost_Food() * list[i].getQuantity_Food();
        System.out.format("%6s %-15S %10gKR. %4d stk.%n", "",
                        list[i].getName_Food(),
                        list[i].getCost_Food(),
                        list[i].getQuantity_Food()
        );
    }
    System.out.println("The Total Amount is: " + totalAmount);
}
```

Comment: Why is `counter` needed instead of just looping until `list.length`?

Comment: Because the cart list may contain less than 10 items.

Comment: I added it in `getTotalCost()`. See my edited answer.